# Connect to RingCentral Meeting Using RingOut API

Tags: phone-call, ringcentral, ringout

Does anyone know how to connect to RingCentral Meeting using RingOut APII and auto dialing MeetingID?

Comment: Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this question is so broad and doesn't provide anything useful for people to offer advice.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the ring-out API does not support dialing a phone number format with the meeting id included. You can call just the phone number then manually enter the meeting Id.